# Java putting hex string into int (without converting)

Tags: android

Hey I have a `String` containing `0xff906000`. Of course, it is way too big to be stored as an dec int. Instead I want the int look exactly as `0xff906000` - keeping it in hex format.

I can declare an `int foo = 0xffffffff;` (not exceeding the int range) so there has to be a way to get my `String` to my int while keeping the exact numbers.

I need all that for `setBackgroundColor(int);`. I could enter the value as a decimal int but I want to keep the aRGB structure which is only possible via hex illustration (0xaaRRGGBB).

```
Integer.parseInt
```

throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0xff906000"`

```
Integer.decode
```

is 'fully' converting the number exceeding the range of `int`

What are the other possibilities?

Answer (score 2):

A computer will store the number in binary. Not hex, and not decimal. And an `int` cannot hold a value outside its' range - for that you'd need a `long`. For display purposes you can call [`Long.toHexString(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString%28long%29) like

```
long foo = 0xff90600000L;
System.out.println("0x" + Long.toHexString(foo));
```

Output is

```
0xff90600000
```

**Edit** For your updated value, use [`Integer.toHexString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)

```
int foo = 0xff906000;
System.out.println("0x" + Integer.toHexString(foo));
```

Output is

```
0xff906000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I only need 4 pairs (8 digits) which HAS to be possible as I can easily declare it without any restrictions. In your example you put 10 digits and I am aware of the fact that an int can't hold 10 but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: @user2875404 `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(0xffffffff));`, and my example *is* your first example.

Comment: No, unless 0xffffffff equals 0xff90600000 and I pretty sure it doesn't 0o

Comment: Sorry, I made a copypaste mistake, now I know what you are talking about. I updated the value

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hopet this will help you to solve your problem.**

It's simply too big for an int (which is 4 bytes and signed) so try this :

```
Long.parseLong("0xff906000", 16);
```

Comment: but if 0xffffffff (8 digits) works in the declaration, why should 0xff906000 (8 digits and slightly lower) not work in code?